# Why is IPV4 represented in base 10

Tags: networking, ip, ipv4

According to the IP dot notation, it is standard to use base 10 representation rather than hexadecimal.

```
127.0.0.1 -> 7F.0.0.1
255.255.255.255 -> FF.FF.FF.FF
10.0.0.1 -> 0A.0.0.1
10.0.0.1/24 -> 0A.0.0.1/18
```

I couldn't find any references in RFC's as to why the convention for IPv4 is base 10, but MAC and IPV6 use Hex by default.

Is there a reason we do this? Or is it purely historic in nature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Decimal is a *de facto* standard; string formatting for IPv4 addresses was never properly standardised. Almost all tools will only take decimal, dotted-quad, notation, but that's not universally true; any tools still using common implementations of `inet_aton()` are likely to handle alternative formats.

`ping` included in the iputils package is a useful example. Take one of google's addresses, and try decimal, hex, and octal dotted-quads:

```
ping -c1 216.58.195.238
ping -c1 0xd8.0x3a.0xc3.0xee
ping -c1 0330.072.0303.0356
```

These all ping the same address, because they all represent the same 32 bits.

But it goes further than that. You don't strictly have to use four octets; classful addressing once specified 8-bit, 16-bit, and 24-bit network prefixes, before the days of classless addressing and variable-length netmasks. Some of that is still baked into `inet_aton()`:

The address above, formatted as 8/8/16 bits:

```
ping -c1 216.58.50158
ping -c1 0330.072.0141756
ping -c1 0xd8.0x3a.0xc3ee
```

Or, formatted as 8/24 bits:

```
ping -c1 216.3851246
ping -c1 0330.016541756
ping -c1 0xd8.0x3ac3ee
```

Or, forget the dots and just throw in 32 bits:

```
ping -c1 3627729902
ping -c1 033016541756
ping -c1 0xd83ac3ee
```

But even better, you don't have to hand over each chunk in the same format:

```
ping -c1 0xd8.072.195.0xee
```

This all leads to a legitimate reminder, however: `inet_aton()` is an old, old function, and has no comprehension of what an IPv6 address is. If you're writing code today, you wouldn't want to use `inet_aton()`, you'd want to use `inet_pton()`, which handles both. Implementations of `inet_pton()` that I've used stick more faithfully to the de-facto standard IPv4 address representation of decimal dotted-quads. For IPv6, which actually does have [an RFC on string representation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952), `inet_pton()` follows the standards!

Comment: inet_aton is regular only for UNIX based systems right? Is there a Windows equivalent syscall?

Comment: `inet_aton()` isn't in the POSIX standard but is commonly implemented by C libraries; I'm afraid I've not done any significant Windows network coding to know for sure, but the documentation seems to suggest they don't implement an `inet_aton()`. They do suggest using `inet_pton()`, which is preferred in any case.

Answer (score 0):

In [RFC 790](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc790), the network numbers are assigned , from there you can get answer to your question.

[RFC 790](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc790) talks about the diffrent network numbers assigned and all these are in 10 base decimal format.

Comment: It talks about decimal and octal representations, but why is there no hexadecimal representation used for IPv4?

Comment: Because it has defined the decimal numbers for ipv4 subnetting, and all the numbers are defined in decimal format itself.

Comment: Why is that though? You could just as easily use hex for subnetting as well as CIDR.

Comment: Yes , we could use , but when the RFC 790 have been written they might decided to go with Decimal numbers. Its in the standards now to use decimal numbers for ipv4 representation.

Comment: So purely historic reasons then? There isn't a good reason not to use hex?

Comment: According to my searches i found this RFC only to answer your question, everyone accepted this format , so yaa purely historic reason, its in the standards the decimal format for ipv4.